# Counting a child table with foreign key, multiple times, with condition

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables,

1. Labels -> id,name,description, user, status
2. Label_connection. -> id, Label_id, categories

So there are multiple categories, let's say 1 => new, 2 => old.

I need the counts of the child table according to the category.

This is what I have right now,

```
SELECT `L`.*, COUNT(DISTINCT LC1.id) as count1, COUNT(DISTINCT LC2.id) as count2 
FROM (`Labels` L) 
LEFT JOIN `Label_connection` LC1 ON `LC1`.`Label_id` = `L`.`id` AND LC1.categories = "1" 
LEFT JOIN `Label_connection` LC2 ON `LC2`.`Label_id` = `L`.`id` AND LC2.categories = "2" 
WHERE `L`.`status` = '0' AND `L`.`user` = 1
GROUP BY `L`.`id` 
ORDER BY `L`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

This does get me the counts correctly, But I am concerned about the multiple joins, as the number of categories will go up.

If anybody can improve this I would be grateful,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For conditional aggregation, you can also use `COUNT DISTINCT .. CASE..WHEN..END`.

Also, your current query is not valid `GROUP BY` (unless `L.id` is a primary key). For details, read: [Error related to only_full_group_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Also, please prefer to use SQL-Standard single quotes around String literals instead of double quotes.

```
SELECT L.id,  
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LC.categories = '1' THEN LC.id END) AS count1, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LC.categories = '2' THEN LC.id END) AS count2 
FROM Labels AS L
LEFT JOIN Label_connection AS LC 
  ON LC.Label_id = L.id
WHERE L.status = '0' AND
      L.user = 1
GROUP BY L.id 
ORDER BY L.id DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: That was perfect, Thanks again, is there a difference between SUM and COUNT, in performance.

Comment: @bibinbaby `COUNT()` **may** be able to use indexing in this case; however you can run `EXPLAIN` statements for both the queries and compare. Since you are counting rows here, count() seems more intuitive though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am going with COUNT. Plus 'L.id' is a primary key, added the group by so that nothing repeats and no null values get returned.

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing it as one `JOIN` with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT `L`.*
     , SUM(CASE WHEN LC.categories = "1" THEN 1 END) as count1
     , SUM(CASE WHEN LC.categories = "2" THEN 1 END) as count2
FROM `Labels` L
LEFT JOIN `Label_connection` LC ON `LC`.`Label_id` = `L`.`id`
WHERE `L`.`status` = '0' AND `L`.`user` = 1
GROUP BY `L`.`id` 
ORDER BY `L`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the answer below from Madhur is using COUNT instead of Sum, is there a big difference between them. I prefer COUNT over SUM. Thanks again.

Comment: @bibinbaby I don't think there would be a significant difference between the two, although having to use `DISTINCT` might slow the `COUNT` down.